# didConnectToHost isn't getting called

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, gcdasyncsocket

I've made a client with a class named "NetClass" using `GCDAsyncSocket` and importing  `CGDAsyncSocket.h`. 
Than in my `LoginViewController` I've called my net class function to connect to the server.

On the server side I see that client is connected, but on the client side `didConnectToHost` doesn't get called.

My `NetClass` call in `LoginViewController`:

```
NetClass *nc = [[NetClass alloc] init];
    [nc ReceiveData:ip login:login password:md5 ];
```

And my `NetClass` functions:

```
- (BOOL)ReceiveData:(NSString *)ip login:(NSString*)login password:(NSString*)password
{
    dispatch_queue_t mainQueue = dispatch_get_main_queue();
    asyncSocket = [[GCDAsyncSocket alloc]initWithDelegate:self delegateQueue:mainQueue];

    NSError *error = nil;
    uint16_t port = 2012;
    if (![asyncSocket connectToHost:ip onPort:port error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error connecting: %@", error);
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"%@",asyncSocket.connectedHost);
        NSData *data = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<MOBIL><refreshall>TRUE</refreshall><user>%@</user><password>%@</password>",@"tst",@"tsts"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSData *enddata = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</ddodata"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        [asyncSocket writeData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
        [asyncSocket readDataToData:enddata  withTimeout:-1 maxLength:-1 tag:1];
        [asyncSocket disconnect];
        return YES;
    }


}
- (void)socket:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock didConnectToHost:(NSString *)host port:(UInt16)port
{
    NSLog(@"%@ %@",@"CONNECTED TO HOST",host);
}

- (void)socketDidDisconnect:(GCDAsyncSocket *)sock withError:(NSError *)err
{
    NSLog(@"socketDidDiscoffffnnect:%p withError: %@", sock, err);
}
```

But at the same time function socketDidDisconnect is getting called

NSLog output :

```
  2012-08-25 14:16:46.312 TacticalView[34981:f803] (null)
2012-08-25 14:16:46.313 TacticalView[34981:f803] socketDidDiscoffffnnect:0x88024d0 withError: (null)
```

I see that asyncSocket not connecting when change ReceiveData like this:

```
 if (![asyncSocket connectToHost:ip onPort:port error:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error connecting: %@", error);
        return NO;
    }
    else
    {
        if ([asyncSocket isConnected])
        {

        NSData *data = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"<MOBIL><refreshall>TRUE</refreshall><user>%@</user><password>%@</password>",@"tst",@"tsts"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        NSData *enddata = [[NSString stringWithFormat:@"</ddodata"] dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

        [asyncSocket writeData:data withTimeout:-1 tag:1];
        [asyncSocket readDataToData:enddata  withTimeout:-1 maxLength:-1 tag:1];
        [asyncSocket disconnect];
        }
        return YES;
    }
```

And if i make socket in my LoginViewController the didConnectToHost method is calling perfectly/ What's wrong& Why i can't use this method in my NetClass?

Comment: the same problem is here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10347066/gcdasyncsocket-no-connection-ios5?s=3d272901-fc83-4870-a97a-c1fc7e78147d but there id no answer

Answer (score 0):

It's a known fact that GCDAsyncSocket does not call the didConnectToHost: method. I suggest using AsyncSocket instead or calling the delegate method yourself.

Comment: What do you mean speaking about calling the delegate method yourself? By the way GCDAsyncSocket isn't calling DidReadData method.. how i can receive some data from server

Comment: And if i make socket in my LoginViewController the didConnectToHost method is calling
 perfectly/ What's wrong& Why i can't use this method in my NetClass?